# Zend framework Checkbox issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, firefox, checkbox

Hi 
The problem with Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox is that when it renders it is creating a hidden input field with the same name as the actual checkbox. So let's see the code:

This is how i create the element inside form:

```
    $onlineCheckbox = $this->createElement('checkbox', 'online_checkbox', array(
      'label'=>'Online:',
      'uncheckedValue'=> '0',
      'checkedValue' => '1'
    ));
```

And this is the Output html look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="online_checkbox" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="online_checkbox" id="online_checkbox" value="1" />
```

Now the problem is that in Other browsers then Firefox i get the needed results via post( if unchecked '0', if checked '1') but in Firefox for both cases i get '0', i know that this is because of that hidden field.
I googled and seems that this issue is not figured out. So my question is how do others manage this , or may be there is a solution to make this work in firefox. Any help will be appreciated. Thank in advance.

EDIT: Thank to @Marcin - i think the problem is in my decorators.
In Firebug i get a messy output, i think that if i will arrange them correctly it will work, again thank @Marcin for pointing out!

Comment: @Centurion. could you provide more details as I just checked your snippet and it seems to work in firefox (I get, if unchecked '0', if checked '1').

Comment: @Marcin, when i test it with plain html it is working, but when i generate with zend, it's not. You tested with a zend ?

Comment: @Centurion. I added your $onlineCheckbox to one of my Zend_Forms, and after the submission I used $mainForm->getValue('online_checkbox'); to get the value of checkbox. It behaves as expected.

Comment: @Marcin Thnks, i edited my post.

Comment: @Centurion maybe you have a duplicate id or name somewhere in your page, Zend checkboxes exists since a quite long time (even before 1.0), and if firefox was unable to handle this hidden checkbox value hack I think it would have been fixed. You are certainly hot by anther bug.

Comment: @Marcin You can be right , try this in a simple form in firefox <code> <input type="checkbox" name="online_checkbox" id="online_checkbox" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="online_checkbox" value="0" />  </code> i reversed so now hidden go after actual checkbox, and you will see that in firefox it is not working.

Comment: @Centurion. yes, it does not work. Based on your edit I assume the problem is solved?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a Dojo enabled form. The Zend_Dojo_View_Helper_CheckBox renders a hidden element and the form element. You can specify the plain old check box like so:

```
$onlineCheckbox = new Zend_Form_Element_CheckBox('online_checkbox', array(
  'label'=>'Online:',
  'uncheckedValue'=> '0', //can be removed, this is the default functionality
  'checkedValue' => '1', //can be removed, this is the default functionality
));
```

This will by pass Zend_Form::createElement()'s plugin loader.

Happy Hacking!

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a IdenticalValidator as workaround for this issue:

```
->addValidator('Identical', false, '1');
```